# Unit testing a UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, xctest, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextFieldDelegate` that performs some formatting as you type by implementing `textField(textField:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:) -> Bool`.

I would like to write a few unit tests for this to check behaviour as key presses are sent, and as deletes are sent. Ideally, I'd do this by creating a `UITextField` in a test, attaching the delegate, and sending key events to it. I don't know how I should send key events to a `UITextField` programatically, though.

I understand I could unit test the delegate directly, but I want to test its interaction with the real `UITextField` implementation.

I would prefer to avoid UI tests if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no good answer to that question. What I usually to because I don't know better is to call the methods like this: `sut.textField.delegate.<delegate_method>`.

Comment: When I unit test a delegate method in place with an existing UITextField, I do so  without querying the text field for anything other than its delegate (like @dasdom's example).